# Why does the fluid rise in the vertical tubes of a venturimeter?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Why does a flowing fluid in a venturimeter rise in the vertical tubes? Why does it need to rise anyway?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the air speeds up in flowing through the throat of the venturi, it pulls a partial vacuum on the walls of the venturi and a tube leading off the throat will therefore experience a suction pressure. That pressure is less than that of the surrounding atmosphere, and if there is fluid inside the tube, that pressure difference will pull on the fluid, causing it to rise in the tube.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple venturi tubes are commonly used for adjusting multiple carburetors on an engine so they will all have the same air flow rate at idle. The engine pulls a partial vacuum on its side of a venturi that is limiting its air flow. A partial vacuum on one end of a tube with the other in water open to atmospheric pressure will lift water into the tube because the vacuum pressure in the tube is lower than atmospheric pressure. The greater the vacuum (the lower the air pressure) in the tube the higher the water will rise in the tube. So with a venturi tube on each carburetor you can adjust all carburetors so the have the same engine side vacuum when the water levels are the same in each venturi tube.